# Is it Possible to submit Oracle Apps Concurrent Program request using HTTP request?

Tags: http, oracle-apps

I want to submit a concurrent Program which have parameters also form a HTML Page using HTML request, It It Possible, anyhow?
What are some Other methods to submit a concurrent program, apart from FND_REQUEST.SUBMIT_REQUEST in a Procedure??

We often submit Concurrent Program request from ORACLE APPS UI,( with Oracle Forms).
But I want to Submit Concurrent program Using URL.
Concurrent Program is already defined, I just need to Submit the request , bY Using URL.
So, is it Possible to do it?

Comment: The question seems a bit broad and provides no code samples. Try add more context to improve the chance of a valuable answer.

Comment: You would have to create a custom page to perform what you are asking.

Comment: @mmmmmpie Can you Please be More Specific, Custom Create Page in HTML.

Comment: I recommend going through very thoroughly the EBS developers guide. There is not enough room on SO for me to tell you how to create a custom page on the EBS OA Framework.